# How to transfer images to Django REST framework applications?

Tags: python, django, image, django-rest-framework, base64

I have learned a few about REST APIs and now while learning, as a practice I am trying to build one using REST framework of Python Django. The difficulty I have faced is that, I cannot make a POST request with images in it from POSTMAN or Curl or any other REST clients. I saw images can be encoded into base64 and then transferred. Unfortunately the internet resources could not help me enough to make me do it on my own. Now can anyone help me and walk out the whole process just to make it easier?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: uploading images? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize `ImageField` of django rest framework (DRF) like this:

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):
"""
A Django REST framework field for handling image-uploads through raw post data.
It uses base64 for encoding and decoding the contents of the file. """

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    import base64
    import six
    import uuid

    # Check if this is a base64 string
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
        if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
            # Break out the header from the base64 content
            header, data = data.split(';base64,')

            # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except Exception:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid image format'))

            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]  # 12 characters are more than enough.
            # Get the file name extension:
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(header)

            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension,)

            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid image format'))

    return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

def get_file_extension(self, header):
    data, format = header.split('/')
    return format
```

And use it like this in your `ModelSerializer`:

```
class AddImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ('image',)
```